# Application crash on progress bar setProgress()

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the value of the progress bar in a fragment but the app crashes with this error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(int)' on a null object reference

This is my code:

```
@BindView(R.id.progressBar1)
ProgressBar progressBar1;   
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    progressBar1.setProgress(90);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_overview, container, false);
}
```

and the progress bar in the XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".modinfosection.TabOverviewFragment">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:clickable="false"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18"
    android:clickable="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to grab this progressView before your inflate your layout or bind the views.  Just switch up your call order a little:

```
@BindView(R.id.progressBar1)
ProgressBar progressBar1;   
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Your inflate call should always happen first thing in this method.
    // Then you can modify the view as you please
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_overview,
                                 container,
                                 false);

    // Since you're using ButterKnife, you need to actually trigger it to
    // process your annotation and bind your view.  Otherwise, it will
    // still be null.
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    // Now you can safely access the progress bar!
    progressBar1.setProgress(90);

    // Be sure to return your inflated root view
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to set your progress bar progress before you've inflated the view, so the progress bar doesn't exist yet.

try setting the progress after the inflate call, or doing it in the onFinishInflate method

Answer (score 1):

Use `ButterKnife.bind(this, view);` when your are using butter knife in order to bind the layout widgets with your activity/fragment.