# How to resolve android InflateException in Binary XML file crash?

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-seekbar

In my scenario, I have developed `CustomSeekbar` long back ago. Now, due to `Android X` version update, my application getting crash `“android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line”`, based on my code analysis, I found the issue happening by overriden `setProgress()` – which is called from ProgressBar's constructor – and there we are calling `onSizeChanged()`.

As of now nothing much reference about this issue in developer community. If any one knows about this issue, Please help me on this.

**Stack Trace**

```
2020-06-13 15:36:44.462 25054-25054/com.goom.project_532 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.goom.project_532, PID: 25054
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #120 in com.goom.project_532:layout/fragment_one_control: Binary XML file line #58 in com.goom.project_532:layout/fragment_two_control:: Error inflating class com.kimso.sims.CustomSeekBar
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58 in com.goom.project_532:layout/fragment_two_control:: Error inflating class com.kimso.sims.CustomSeekBar
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1263)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at com.semcon.jimsa.cfx.fragment.gymControlFragment.onCreateView(gymControlFragment.java:407)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at com.semcon.jimsa.roboguicehelper.KubaAppCompatActivity.onStart(KubaAppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1433)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3512)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2175)
2020-06-13 15:36:44.464 25054-25054/com.goom.project_532 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void java.util.List.clear()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.updateGestureExclusionRects(AbsSeekBar.java:1001)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setThumbPos(AbsSeekBar.java:985)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.updateThumbAndTrackPos(AbsSeekBar.java:878)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.updateDrawableBounds(AbsSeekBar.java:1942)
        at android.widget.ProgressBar.onSizeChanged(ProgressBar.java:2196)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onSizeChanged(AbsSeekBar.java:837)
        at com.kimso.sims.CustomSeekBar.onSizeChanged(jimsaSeekBar.java:242)
        at com.kimso.sims.CustomSeekBar.setProgressInternally(jimsaSeekBar.java:435)
        at com.kimso.sims.CustomSeekBar.setProgress(jimsaSeekBar.java:312)
        at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:376)
        at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.<init>(AbsSeekBar.java:184)
        at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:89)
        at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:85)
        at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:81)
        at com.kimso.sims.CustomSeekBar.<init>(jimsaSeekBar.java:82)
            ... 48 more
```

Comment: It looks like there is problem in `onSizeChanged()` method. Please, attach the code for the method as well.

Comment: Show xml and java import classes

Comment: @cgb_pandey Please check it I have updated `onSizeChanged()`. From the method inside if you click `super.onSizeChanged` it will go `AbsSeekbar`.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have updated my code. Please check it and provide me some solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358427/fatal-exception-main-process-com-goom-project-532-pid-25054-android-view-inf

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Page not found. please provide me possible solution, If you have any idea about this.

Comment: Can you attach the code for constructor from where `setProgress()` is called?

Comment: @cgb_pandey I have updated Please check it

Comment: @Devapp `Page not found` both are same.same account

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set progress and call "onSizeChanged" at the same time in the constructor, before the view is attached to its parent and a window. That is not possible and you're getting a NullPointerException because of this issue. Try setting the progress on `View.onAttachedToWindow()` method by overriding it instead.

Edit: Well you can override the method in your `CustomSeekBar` if you just
write "onAttachedToWindow()" in the editor, just like you did at "onSizeChanged". Also you don't need to override "onSizeChanged", in fact that causes a wrong behavior in the code. Swapping width and height may not work there reliably.

Sample code would look like this I presume:

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow()
{
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    // I believe you are trying to change the width-height depending on the orientation,
    // so if the orientation is vertical you can swap the width and height.
    // Remember this in the view though, so you wouldn't accidentally change it
    // multiple times. Or, if you change it outside of the view lifecycle
    // in the code, make sure to reset the state so you can put width-height
    // properly again.

    // This holds if the width-height change is applied.
    // Define this as "private boolean layoutParametersChanged"
    // at the top of the class.
    if (!layoutParametersChanged)
    {
        // Mark as changed for the initial process.
        layoutParametersChanged = true;

        // I assume "1" stands for "Vertical" in your code.
        // If it is horizontal, you shouldn't do a change.
        if (mOrientation == 1)
        {
            // If you are using "wrap_content" or "match_parent" don't use them here.
            // This check determines a fixed width and height, such as "60dp 60dp"
            // for "layout_width" and "layout_height" parameters in the xml.
            if (getLayoutParams().width > 0 && getLayoutParams().height > 0)
            {
                getLayoutParams().width = getHeight();
                getLayoutParams().height = getWidth();
                requestLayout();
            }
            else
            {
                // Wait for the layout to be attached, because if this is
                // called, it's still not attached. To make sure, get
                // width and height first. If they are non-zero, you can
                // apply the change. Otherwise, attach a listener.
                if (getWidth() > 0 && getHeight() > 0)
                {
                    getLayoutParams().width = getHeight();
                    getLayoutParams().height = getWidth();
                    requestLayout();
                }
                else
                {
                    // This will be called once the view dimensions are set,
                    // so you can safely use the width and height here.
                    getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onPreDraw()
                        {
                            if (getViewTreeObserver().isAlive())
                                getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                            getLayoutParams().width = getHeight();
                            getLayoutParams().height = getWidth();
                            requestLayout();

                            // Return true here.
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great find. Could you please help me how to do `View.onAttachedToWindow()`. provide some code if possible.

Comment: @Devapp Edited the answer, attached a sample code. Side note: You can also call "setProgress" in that method safely.

Comment: your answer I cant able to understand the code. You mean instead of `onSizeChanged` do I need to change above code?

Comment: Yes. Overriding "onSizeChanged" and calling the super method with different parameters  doesn't help you because everything is decided already after that method is called, you need to change the layout params themselves in order to change view width and height and request another layout, where the above code does that.

Comment: In this case if I comment `onSizeChanged` after that also I am getting Same issue.

Comment: You cannot get an inflate exception if you include this code and call the "setProgress" method properly. Make sure it's not called before "onAttachedToWindow" method is called and you will be fine. Or, you are getting a different exception which I'm not aware of, that being said it's a whole different case.

Comment: I tried it but same issue happening. Before call `setProgress` I placed `onAttachedToWindow()` even I am getting same issue.

Comment: I don't mean it like that. `onAttachedToWindow()` is called by itself, you shouldn't call it manually. You need to call `setProgress()` in `onAttachedToWindow()`, not the other way around.

Comment: Could you please update your code inside `onAttachedToWindow()` where I need to call `setProgress()`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you called `init()` so early which caused the `NullPointerException` eventually because your `CustomSeekBar` object isn't fully constructed. Remember that until the last line of your `CustomSeekBar` constructor, you cannot call any method such as `setProgress()` which will internally use the same object that is being created(as this is the case here).

Initially in the constructor you called `init()` > `setProgress()` > `setProgressDetail()` > `setSeekBarChange()` > `setThumb()` > `updateThumbAndTrackPos()` > `setThumbPos()` > `updateGestureExclusionRects()` > `mGestureExclusionRects.clear()` where `mGestureExclusionRects` is null because it isn't yet initialized.
**Note: here ">" means "which in turn calls"**

Instead, if you want to set the progress to 0 initially, then create a `int` variable initialized to 0 and then update it later from your `xml` to keep track of the progress in your `CustomSeekBar` view as :

```
public class CustomSeekBar extends AbsSeekBar {
    private int mStartProgress;
    public CustomSeekBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.yourSeekBarStyle);
    }

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();

        // obtain attribute from xml and set it
        final TypedArray a = ........;
        mStartProgress = a.getInt(R.styleable.yourSeekBarStyle_startProgress, mStartProgress);
        // ........
        a.recycle();
    }

    private void init(){
        // do not call method like setProgress() here
        // as the object is still in the process of
        // being created.
        mStartProgress = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `setProgress(0)` already initiated. I replaced `mStartProgress = 0;` even it is not working.

Comment: Looks like, I think same issue I am facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303180/application-crash-on-progress-bar-setprogress

Comment: Nope, this is a different issue. Do you really need to call `init()` in the constructor? If you want to set the progress as 0 initially, I guess that's already handled by your `CustomSeekBar` class.

Comment: Yes `setProgress(0)` already initialised and handled into CustomSeekBar class. Above code I tried but it is also giving same issue. Is it possible to update my code and post it here?

Comment: Can you tell me what would happen if you don't call `init()` in the constructor?

Comment: @cg_pandey in my code I didn't used init(). Could you please check above my code post. Your asking about `setProgress(0)`?

Comment: Please edit the code to reflect the changes. Don't call `this.init(attrs, null)` in both of the constructor.

Comment: I have updated my code please review it. also my extends `public class CustomSeekBar extends AppCompatSeekBar { ….. }` not AbsSeekBar.

Comment: Do all other stuffs but don't call `setProgress(0)` in your `init()` method.

Comment: after this call `public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {….}` it is Directly going `public synchronized void setProgress(int progress) {....}` this method. I removed `setProgress(0)`. This is I found by using debugging.

Comment: I tried my best but same issue I am facing. Is there any other way?

Comment: yeah because you called `this.setProgress(0)` which is the overriden method with signature `public synch.....`

Comment: Please follow this guide to refactor your code for `CustomSeekBar` : https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view 
You can also search for other custom `SeekBar` implementation in github to learn the better way to implement custom components.